# Open a file only if it exists using vim

Tags: files, vim

When opening a file using vim, even if the file doesn't exist, vim is opening a blank file under the name that I pass as param. How can I make vim to open a file only if it exists?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/16073807/4023950

Answer (score 1):

```
[ -e $1 ] && vim $1
```

is the core of a simple solution. I tested it by writing this one line to a file "pv.cmd" (p as in protected...) and defining a "new command" with

```
alias pv='source pv.cmd'
```

All this I think is needed because we want it to work via the (one and only, I hope...) argument.

Now I can go

```
pv filename<enter>
```

And, if that filename does not exist ( "-e" test), you get a new prompt line in 0.000 seconds (I really did `time pv jjjjjj`).

Otherwise the file simply opens in vim.

And even just pv without an arg starts vim - the welcome screen.

You have so many options from here: how you name your "pv" alias? A fast but risky "v" ? Where do you define this alias best? Do you alias over vim or vi? Make that one liner a bash executable? A shell function?

You know I wondered before if it's me or vim when that happens (editing an unwanted empty file). But now I go `:q` instantly, and no file ever gets created.

You cannot test that line in pv.cmd directly because it needs a first argument (called "$1" in bash). I think an alias to source a oneliner that checks argument `$1` is the minimum required.

*...or is there an OPTION IN VIM?*

---

Using a function amounts to quite to the same, I would say --- matter of taste and how you are organized (or the how the SYSTEM organizes YOU :-)

Answer (score 1):

A cursory glance at the various Vim help files does not reveal whether this is possible without resorting to using a Vim script.  If you use `:e filename` in Vim and `filename` does not exist, the editor will open a new buffer of that name and will save the buffer to that name when you use `:w`.  This is usually what you would *want* to do.

To require that a filename exists when *starting* Vim, you can overload the `vim` command with a shell function:

```sh
vim () {
    if [ -e "$1" ] || [ -z "$1" ]; then
        command vim ${1:+"$1"}
    else
        printf 'No such file or directory: %s\n' "$1" >&2
        return 1
    fi
}
```

This would allow you to

1. only edit an existing file, and
2. start Vim with *no* file on the command line (this would enable you to create a new file with `:e filename` in Vim).

The two tests, `[ -e "$1" ]` and `[ -z "$1" ]`, detects whether the first argument to the function exists as a filename, or whether it's empty.

The parameter expansion `${1:+"$1"}` will expand to the given filename, quoted, or to nothing if there was no filename given.

`command vim` ensures that we don't call our function recursively.

---

To also handle possible options that a user may pass to Vim, one would have to parse the command line arguments and remove the arguments that are filename operands that corresponds to non-existing names:

```sh
vim () {
    dashdash=false

    for arg do
        use_arg=false

        case $arg in
            --)
                dashdash=true
                use_arg=true
                ;;
            -*)
                if "$dashdash"; then
                    [ -e "$arg" ] && use_arg=true
                else
                    use_arg=true
                fi
                ;;
            *)
                [ -e "$arg" ] && use_arg=true
        esac

        if "$use_arg"; then
            set -- "$@" "$arg"
        else
            printf 'No such file or directory (skipping): %s\n' "$arg" >&2
        fi

        shift
    done

    unset arg dashdash use_arg

    command vim "$@"
}
```

The only tricky bit here is that an `--` argument on the command line signals the end of options.  This means that every argument after `--` needs to be tested as a filename, whereas while we haven't seen a `--` we can skip the `-e` test on anything that starts with a dash.

This function would open the editor with a blank buffer if no existing filenames were given.

Comment: Just to add, I've discovered it's possible to alias `vim!` to `command vim` to bypass this behaviour when you explicitly want to edit a non-existent filename.